# Show that the center of a group is an invariant subgroup using symmetry

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

In an interview with Pierre Deligne, he stated an example to show how important the symmetry is.

We want to show that the center of a group is invariant(normal).

> “An invariant(normal) subgroup is a subgroup stable by all inner automorphisms. I have been able to define the center. It is hence stable by all symmetries of the data. So it is obvious that it is invariant(normal)"
>
> For me, this was a revelation: the power of the idea of symmetry. That Tits did not need to go through a step-by-step proof, but instead could just say that symmetry makes the result obvious, has influenced me a lot. I have a very big respect for symmetry, and in almost every one of my papers there is a symmetry-based argument.

I understand the first sentence, and I know how to use it to prove the statement. However, I have no idea what are those "symmetries of the data". What are these symmetries and how to use them to make the statment obvious?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly he means by "I have been able to define the center" either

Answer (score 3):

Looking at $Z(G)=\{h| hg=gh\,,\forall g\in G\}$, it appears obvious by the symmetry of $g$ and $h$, that, since $ghg^{-1}=h\,,\forall g$, that $gZ(G)g^{-1}=Z(G)$.  That is,  $Z(G)$ is inner-automorphism invariant,  or normal.